# Add red border around selectize dropdownlist when asp.net mvc4 validation fails

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, selectize.js

I am using selectize framework for my drop down list in asp.net mvc4. I was able to change css on every form field that is bound to asp.net mvc4's validation engine.

What is the way to go about making a border around the dropdownlist for selectize as it's not working. It's bound to the validation because I can pick up the error in the summary if nothing is selected, I just want to use a red border around it too.

Here is a jsFiddle example I found on the 
    http://jsfiddle.net/249Wz/4/ of a selectize drop down.

and this is the css I want to use

```
 .input-validation-error {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background-color: #fee;
  }
```

Comment: The plugin hides the original `<select>` element so you need to style the element created by the plugin (refer updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/249Wz/120/) - although you should be handling the `.change()` event so that the style is removed when a user selects a valid value

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I was able to take it one step further and use.selectize-input, to highlight just the drop down box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Stephen's response I was able to solve it by using the JFiddle example he provided. However, I used, ".selectize-input"  to just border the drop down component rather than the surrounding div. I did have to make sure I called !important on the css error class definitions otherwise something else was blocking my addition.